# How to Scale Azure cloud service up and down from Rest API with WebAPI

Tags: azure

I am creating a demo where I need to be able to scale up my cloud service deployment from a WebAPI.

I went over the rest API documentation and didn't seem to find what I need.

Is it possible to use Service Management API to scale a cloud service up and down ?

Alternative I will just enable auto scale on a queue and then post messages to the queue to get it to scale up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there's no such function in Service Management REST API for scaling. Since the number of instances for a particular role is stored in the service configuration file, what you would need to do is read this configuration information using [`Get Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) operation, locate the `Instances` node and change the value of `count` attribute. Then you would need to call [`Change Deployment Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx) for new instance count to be effective.

Comment: It seems I'm running late by time!, If this approach is used, will the cloud service instance restart? Meaning that if it's a Web Role, what would happen to current request that IIS is serving?