# Azure website scaling

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Can I scale azure web apps/api apps using Azure Management libraries? I basically want to implement scaling up and down of web apps to handle throttling. Hence, I need to scale the web app and api apps via C# code. Any pointers to any apprpriate library/ ReST API?

With teh help of the answer mentioned below, I understand how to update the APP Service plan to scale out, however, I am not able to find webHostingPlanName for my APP Service. I tried with the below code, and hosting plan always comes out to be null.

```
        var regionName = "myregion";

        var credentials = GetCredentials();

        var websiteManagementClient = CloudContext.Clients.CreateWebSiteManagementClient(credentials);

        var webSpaces = websiteManagementClient.WebSpaces.List();
        var webSpace = webSpaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GeoRegion == regionName);
        if (webSpace == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No webspace for region {0} found", regionName));
        }

        var webHostingPlans = websiteManagementClient.WebHostingPlans.List(webSpace.Name);
        var webHostingPlan = webHostingPlans.FirstOrDefault();// this is null always, I know an APP service exists in this region
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Scale Azure cloud service up and down from Rest API with WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197445/how-to-scale-azure-cloud-service-up-and-down-from-rest-api-with-webapi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, We can use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Websites library to scale up and down of web apps.
Using method `WebSiteManagementClient.WebHostingPlans.UpdateAsync(webspaceName, webHostingPlanName, webHostingPlanUpdateParameters)` to implement it.

I had done a demo to do this. The following are the my detail steps:

**1.Install the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites that we can get it from the [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/).**

**2.Create the WebsiteManagementClient object**.

I used the cert to create the websitemagement client.

- Create a cert with makecert.exe that is under the VS folder after install the VS.

  ```
  makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=[CertificateName]" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "[CertificateName].cer
  ```

[image]

- Upload the. Cert file to Azure portal then get the thumbprint

[image]
**3. Using the code to generate the WebsiteManagementClient object**

```
          public static X509Certificate2 GetCert(string thumbprint)
    {

        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
        if (certCollection.Count <= 0) return null;
        X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
        return cert;
    }
```

`var cert = GetCert(string thumbprint)
 var subscriptionId ="Your subscriptionId"
var webSiteManagementClient = new  WebSiteManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert));`

**4.Construct the WebHostingPlanUpdateParameters**

```
var webHostingPlanUpdateParameters = new WebHostingPlanUpdateParameters
                {
                    NumberOfWorkers = 1, //the number of the instances
                    SKU = SkuOptions.Standard, 
                    WorkerSize = WorkerSizeOptions.Small
                };
```

**5.Update the WebHostingPlans with code**

```
client.WebHostingPlans.UpdateAsync(webspaceName, webHostingPlanName, webHostingPlanUpdateParameters);
```

> Note: If you try to run the project on the Azure. Please refer to document [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/). *Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application*

Comment: Scaling out is possible as well? or only scale up and down?

Comment: @Purbasha It can be used for both scaling out and scaling up. SKU and WorkerSize are used for scaling up .NumberOfWorkers  is used for scaling out . But SKU has no value Premium. If want to scale up the App service plan with Premium pricing tier . Have a try to use to the  [new library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites) in the preview.

Comment: I am not able to find webHostingPlanName for my APP Service. I tried with the below code, and hosting plan always comes out to be null

Comment: Please have a try to debug the code and watch the value of the `webHostingPlans` and  `webSpace.Name` to check it.